# regex to remove commas between quotes in Oracle 11.2g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

My code is:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited;
DECLARE
  v_line_unclean   VARCHAR2(32767); -- 32767 BYTES
  v_line_clean     VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_clean_val     VARCHAR2(32767);
  SQLSMT           VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_line_in_record INTEGER;
  pattern varchar2(15) := '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)';
  v_name           VARCHAR2(50);
  v_first_column   VARCHAR2(200);
  EMP_FILE UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(9000000);
  EMP_FILE         := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('EGIS_FILE_DIR','TEST.csv','R', 32767); -- open the file from oracle directory
  v_line_in_record := 0;                                         --we skip the first line
  IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(EMP_FILE) THEN
    LOOP
      v_line_in_record := v_line_in_record + 1;
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_line_in_record);
      BEGIN
        UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(EMP_FILE,v_line_unclean);
        IF v_line_in_record = 1 THEN-- first record here
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        ELSIF v_line_in_record = 2 THEN-- second record here (header)
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_line_unclean);
          v_first_column   := SUBSTR(v_line_unclean,1,instr(v_line_unclean,',',10,1)-1);
          dbms_output.put_line('1st '||REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_line_unclean, '[^,]+', 1, 1));
        ELSE -- body records here);
          SELECT REPLACE(v_line_unclean,'((\)|^).*?(\(|$))|,', '\1')INTO v_line_clean FROM DUAL;
          SQLSMT := 'INSERT INTO SITE_CONFIG_2G VALUES('''||v_line_clean||''')';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSMT;
        END IF;
        COMMIT;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_lINE(SQLSMT);
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_lINE('NO DATA FOUND EXCEPTION');
        EXIT;
      WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_lINE('TO MANY ROW EXCEPTION');
        EXIT;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlcode||sqlerrm);
        ROLLBACK;
        EXIT;
      END;--EXCEPTION
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(EMP_FILE);
END;
```

### **Result** :

```
INSERT INTO SITE_CONFIG_2G VALUES('1,gold,benz,2018,1,blue,"34,000,000",6.4,new,CSV')
INSERT INTO SITE_CONFIG_2G VALUES('2,silver,bmw,2016,1,silver,"51,000,000",6.5,New,CSV')
INSERT INTO SITE_CONFIG_2G VALUES('3,bronze,range,2017,1,light-blue,"24,000,000",7.8,New,RVS')
```

I would like to remove commas between quotes in `"24,000,000"` to give me `"24000000"`

Current result is:

```
3,bronze,range,2017,1,light-blue,"24,000,000",7.8,New,RVS
```

Expected result is:

```
3,bronze,range,2017,1,light-blue,"24000000",7.8,New,RVS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this.

```
    select regexp_replace('1,gold,benz,2018,1,blue,"34,000,000",6.4,new,CSV',
'(")([^"|,]+)(,)([^"|,]+)(,)([^"|,]+)(")',
'\1\2\4\6\7') from dual;
```

Comment: Thank arunb2w..it worked, but I still need your help..how can the above work for this expression*****                                                               
SELECT REPLACE(v_line_unclean,',',''',''')INTO v_line_clean FROM DUAL;    so i can have result in the format '3','bronze','range','2017','1','light-blue','"24000000"','7.8','New','RVS'

Comment: arunb2w.. can I get a result with this result . INSERT INTO DEMO_TEST VALUES(3,'bronze','range','2017','1','light-blue','24000000','7.8','New','RVS'); thanks

Comment: I don't see any commas inside those double quotes. What we need to replace here?

Comment: thanks have found a way to resolve it.select regexp_replace(v_line_unclean,'(")([^"|,]+)(,)([^"|,]+)(,)([^"|,]+)(")','\1\2\4\6\7') INTO v_line_clean from dual;
          v_line_regex := REPLACE(v_line_clean,',',''',''');
          SQLSMT := 'INSERT INTO DEMO_TEST VALUES('''||v_line_regex||''')';
          --- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSMT;                                                 but it not working for "10,000" but it's working for "10,000,000'                   Result == INSERT INTO DEMO_TEST VALUES('1','gold','benz','2018','"10','000"','blue','"34000000"','6.4','new','CSV')